# Group actions: What are they?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Im currently studying pure maths and I am unsure as to what a group action is? I understand that a group action is defined as:

For a g $\in$ G, let G be a group and for a s $\in$ S be a set, then a group action is:

$\rhd$ : G $\times$ S $\rightarrow$ S

So for example what does: g $\rhd$ S mean? And then g$_1$ $\rhd$ ( g$_2 \rhd$ S )

Also what is the test for finding group actions?

Comment: Group actions are a way to formalise associating elements of a group $G$ with permutations of some set $S$. $\rhd$ is just the name of the function that takes an element of the group $G$, $g$ and an element of the set $S$, $s$ and maps the pair $(g,s)$ it to whatever element of $S$ the permutation associated with $g$ maps $s$ to.

Comment: The symbols you should be trying to make sense of are $g \rhd s$ where $g \in G$ and $s \in S$.  Similarly, $g_1 \rhd (g_2 \rhd s)$ for a particular element $s$.

Comment: What do you mean by "a test for finding group actions"?

Comment: I suspect when Connor says  "a test for finding group actions" he is referring to the axioms of group actions. These axioms are necessary to make the mapping actually permutations of the set $S$ and hence of interest to us. Of course we could arbitrarily define a function that maps elements such as $(g,s)$ into some element of $S$ but unless we have certain properties (i.e. the axioms) they are not going to be permutations of $S$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be a group and $S$ be a set. One says that $G$ acts on $S$ if and only if there exists a map $\cdot:G\times S\rightarrow S$ such that for all $s\in S,1_G\cdot s=s$ ($1_G$ acts trivially on S) and for all $g_1,g_2\in G$, $g_1\cdot(g_2\cdot s)=(g_1g_2)\cdot s$ (the action is compatible with the group structure of $G$). Usually one write $g\cdot s$ instead of $\cdot(g,s)$.

Your definition of group action is laking the last two properties.

An equivalent definition of group action is a group morphism from $G$ to $\mathfrak{S}(S)$, the group of bijections of $S$.

Let us examine some examples.

- A group $G$ acts on itself by left translation through $(g,h)\mapsto gh$.
- A group $G$ acts on itself by right translation through $(g,h)\mapsto hg^{-1}$ (try to understand why I chose to multiply by $g^{-1}$ instead of $g$).
- A group $G$ acts on itself by conjugation through $(g,h)\mapsto ghg^{-1}$.
- $\mathfrak{S}_n$ acts on $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ through $(\sigma,i)\mapsto\sigma(i)$.
- Let $E$ be a $k$-vector space, $\textrm{GL}(E)$ acts on $E$ through $(g,x)\mapsto g(x)$.

Let me try to motivate the definition of group action. If $E$ is a $k$-vector space, then $k$ acts on $E$ through scalar multiplication. In that sense, the notion of group action is a way to generalize the definition of vector space.

Answer (score 0):

You are given a group $G$ and a set $S$. Note that the set of permutations of $S$ is  also group (of order n! if $S$ happens to be finite, of cardinality $n$. But $S$ could very well be infinite).

If there is a way of *associating* to each element of $G$ a permutation of $S$ we say $G$ acts on $S$: such as association must be homomorphic.

Often people write $g.s$ to mean the effect of the permutation associated with $g$ on the element $s\in S$. Homomorphic condition translates to (in this notation) $g_1.(g_2.s)= (g_1g_2).s$ and $e.s=s$ for all $s\in S, g_1,g_2\in S$.

Consider the infinite set of points on the plane. Among all permutations of this infinite set consider the following set of permutations $T_n$ defined for each integer: $T_n{x\choose y}= {x+ny\choose y} $. Note that these permutations shuffle points horizontally, and so of very restricted kind.

Now check that the permutation $$T_{n+m}= T_n\circ T_m\qquad T_0=\rm identity\hskip2in(*) $$  Thus we have associated one permutation $T_n$ for each integer $n$, and it is  homomorphic association, by $(*)$.

So we can say the group of integers **Z** acts on the set of points on the plane.

Exercise: can you give a vertically shuffling action in the same setup?